# Blog comments duplicate content paradox

Tags: seo, blog, duplicate-content

I have a blog on this page:

```
domain.com/Blog/5/some-title
```

Below the blog entry it says, "click for comments".

You click the link, and it goes to:

```
domain.com/Blog/5/some-title/Comments
```

For user experience, the blog content is displayed, with the comments displayed below it.  It goes on multiple pages, such as:

```
domain.com/Blog/5/some-title/Comments/Page1
domain.com/Blog/5/some-title/Comments/Page2
```

I want all the comments to be indexed by engines, but, each page displays the blog content on it!

I don't want to canonical it to the blog URL, because the comments wont be indexed.  I don't want to not display the blog, because it takes peoples comments out of context and isn't so user friendly.

Any way around this?  Assume there are thousands of comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search engine spiders typically do not deal in cookies or Javascript.

If you are generating the comments page with a script on every request (not likely if you're getting thousands of comments) you can display the blog entry content when the visitor has a cookie of some variety set.

If you are serving up a static HTML page from a cache, add a Javascript call which loads the blog entry content with an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

Load the whole page, including comments - this is your canonical URL. Then handle pagination of the comments by JavaScript.

If you specifically want them to be on a different URL like you put above, then use JavaScript to remove them from the blog page and replace them with the links as above. Then use your robots file to ignore `*/Comments/*`.

Comment: This doesn't work well if you have 20,000 comments!

Answer (score 0):

> Any way around this? Assume there are thousands of comments.

Should we assume that there are thousands of comments on your blog in total, or thousands of comments *per blog entry*?

If you're talking about blog entries that get a few dozen or even 100+ comments, please just keep everything at one URL - blog entry and all comments, no clicking a link to get to the comments on another URL, no weird javascripts.

When you start getting above 1-200 comments per post, that's when you need to look at more exotic solutions.

Are you using a blogging tool / CMS? If so, which one?